# Q.all returns the async function instead of the value I want to resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

Here is my small demo script.

The idea is that at some point in my promise chain, I will call `doAll` which calls `Q.all` to process a batch of async operations. The result is then returned before I proceed to the next promise chain because that next method I will call might actually need the result from `Q.all`.

I kind of feel my code below isn't doing my end goal, but right now, `doAll` just resolves the function back instead of the value I really want to resolve. `Q.all` didn't even wait for `Q.delay` to do anything.

**Output**

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ node p.js
Starting step 1
the then after doAll
[ [Function: doAsync], [Function: doAsync] ]
```

**Code**

```
var Q = require('q');

function doAsync() {
    console.log('doing async');
    return Q.delay(3000).thenResolve('finished');
};

// A helper function that calls a batch of async operations
// In real code this could be a mix of async calls.
function doAll() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    Q.all([doAsync, doAsync])
     .then(function (results) {
        deferred.resolve(results);
      });
    return deferred.promise;
};

// In real app this function may have a chained
// of promises (step1 - 3)
//     step1()
//       .step2()
//       .step3()
//       .doAll()
//       .tearDown()
//       .done();
// But here we just imagine all these steps in
// a single function.
function starter() {
    console.log("Starting step 1");
    return Q.delay(1000);
}

// Idea:
// We start with 1 or more steps, then we
// call doAll and wait for all of them to complete
// before return the batch result.
starter()
  .then(function () {
    doAll()
    .then(function(results) {
        console.log("the then after doAll");
        console.log(results);
    })
});
```

The code above using `Q.delay` is inspired by this demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/jfromaniello/FRRxM/3/light/

Comment: Why isn't `doAll()` just `return Q.all([doAsync, doAsync]);` and nothing more.  You're manually creating a new promise when you can just use the one that `Q.all()` returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get array of functions in the results because `Q.all` should receive as argument array of promises and not array of factory functions creating that promises. Documentation you can find [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall).

Also, you don't need to create another deferred object to fetch results from `Q.all` and pass it to next async function:

**JavaScript**

```
function doAsync1() {
    console.log('Async 1');
    return Q.delay(3000).thenResolve('finished1');
};

function doAsync2() {
    console.log('Async 2');
    return Q.delay(3000).thenResolve('finished2');
};

function starter() {
    console.log("Starter");
    return Q.delay(1000);
}

function doAll() {
    return Q.all([doAsync2(), doAsync2()]);
}

starter().
    then(doAsync1).
    then(doAll).
    then(function(results) {
        console.log("after doAll");
        console.log(results);
    });
```

**Result**

```
Starter
Async 1
Async 2
Async 2
after doAll
["finished2", "finished2"]
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/St7YS/1/

Comment: Ah indeed. I have to call the function ``doAsync`` in the ``Q.all`` to return the promise! That was my mistake. Thanks for pointing out.